# What is the difference between smart class parameters and smart variables

Tags: puppet, theforeman

In puppet foreman UI, there is smart class parameters and smart variables. Smart class parameters comes up with override feature where as smart variables not;  So i am wondering whether we can say that smart variables are subset of smart class parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Smart Variables allow Foreman to set global variables that can be consumed by Puppet manifests. This is usually more for backwards compatibility, when using manifests/classes that are not parameterized.

If a class is parameterized, then the way to set those parameters via Foreman is Smart Class Parameters.